# Comprobar si query trae datos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente query.

Como puedo comprobar que realmente tenga datos de retorno?
o como saber cuando regrese vacio o null?

```
SqlConnection conreq = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
              SqlCommand comreq = new SqlCommand("select ...", conreq);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(comreq);
              adap.Fill(dt);
              dataGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Estas mostrando los datos en un grid, sino visualizas registros es que no hay datos, un datatable nunca va a ser null porque tu lo instancias y realizas el Fill(), a donde apunto es que no veo que necesitas comprobar si lo visualizas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con dt.Rows.Count, esto para obtener el numero de filas que tienen el resultado.

```
SqlConnection conreq = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
              SqlCommand comreq = new SqlCommand("select ...", conreq);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(comreq);
              adap.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //tiene al menos una fila
dataGrid.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Espero te sirva,saludos.